# How to add value between tags using XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have looked a bunch of XML samples using `XDocument` and `XElement` but they all seem to have self closing tags like `<To Name="John Smith"/>`. I need to do the following:

```
<To Type="C">John Smith</To>
```

I thought the following would work and tried to look at the object model of the Linq.XML class, but I'm off just a tad (**see line below that is not working**)

```
new XElement("To", new XAttribute("Type", "C")).SetValue("John Smith")
```

Any assistance on how to get the XML formed properly is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So is the question how you make `<To Type="C">John Smith</To>` become `<To Type="C" Name="John Smith"/>`?

Comment: In future, please tell us what's wrong with what you've tried - "I'm off just a tad" doesn't really explain what's wrong.

Comment: @Jon - my 2nd line is what I tried and it did not work. `new XElement("To", new XAttribute("Type", "C")).SetValue("John Smith")` What am I missing here sir? I said *off a tad* and the next line had code that does not work. Result = StackOverflow question. Please clarify.

Comment: "it did not work" is still not enough detail. That's like going to a doctor and expecting a diagnosis after only giving the information that you're not feeling well, but without giving any symptoms. Did you get a compile-time error? If so, what? A failure at execution time? Just not the expected result? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd use:

```
new XElement("To", new XAttribute("Type", "C"), "John Smith");
```

Any plain text content you provide within the `XElement` constructor ends up as a text node.

You *can* call `SetValue` separately of course, but as it doesn't return anything, you'll need to store a reference to the element in a variable first.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
  new XElement("To", new XAttribute("Type", "C"), "John Smith")
```